# How to stop Breadth-first search recursive function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search

I want to stop my Breadth-first search function after I reach the specified cell.

For now I show an alert after reaching the specified cell, but the remaining nodes are still visited. You can see this behaviour [here](http://phil0s0pher.tk/) (Choose Breadth-first search please).

```
function drawBreadthFirstSearch(current, start, last, queue, animation_speed) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (queue.length >= 0) {
            current = queue.shift();

            if (current !== last) {
                current.color = "#c6e0b4";
                current.changeColor();
            } else {
                alert('The end!')
                return
            }

            var childs = checkNeigbors(current.i, current.j)
            if (childs) {
                childs.forEach(function (child) {
                    if (child.visited === false) {
                        child.color = "green";
                        child.changeColor();

                        queue.push(child)
                        child.visited = true;
                        drawBreadthFirstSearch(current, start, last, queue, animation_speed)
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }, animation_speed);
}
```

Function `checkNeigbors` returns array of cells.

Changing the `forEach` to a `for` doesn't help.

Comment: you have some missing `;`. In the 'The End' line and the `return` after it there are no `;`. Also on the `queue.push(child)` ...

Comment: thx, but its don't solve my problem.

Comment: This algorithm isn't breadth-first, but depth-first and in addition to that (I'm not exactly proficient when it comes to javascript) looks like it's asynchronous, which makes aborting when the correct function was found tricky.

Comment: @Paul, it is breadth-first (don't be mislead by the link where you should first choose "breadth first").

Comment: @NikitaYunoshev, as a side note, I don't think the current animation is a fair comparison with the animation for depth-first. For breadth-first you animate all nodes that are at the same level at the same time, while in depth-first you nicely show every visited node, one by one. I think it should be the same for breadth-first. Is that something you want or not?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. Following the link you need to choose Bread-first search

Comment: @NikitaYunoshev sry, my bad. Should've noticed that. Still, the major issue is the fact that this code works asynchronously. You could either define some kind of callback to check whether the algorithm terminated that will be checked by all pending recursive calls or clear the queue when you hit the target-node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it continues, is that the `forEach` loop will launch several recursive calls, which all start a timer. So the number of pending timers increases as the width of your search tree is increasing. And ending the callback of *one* timer will not stop the other pending timers from executing their callbacks.

One quick fix is to make the queue empty as soon as you find a match. As the timer callback only does something when the queue is not empty, *and* the queue reference is shared across all function calls, you can avoid any further search that way.

```
        queue.length = 0; // <--- add this.
        alert('The end!')
        return
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. It helped. I understand that forEach launching several recursive calls, but I'm has tried "queue = [ ]" and it doesn't helped)

Comment: `queue = []` does not help, because that only changes the local variable which will then point to a *new* array in memory without affecting the memory location of the *original* array: it gets detached from the original array that `queue` referred to, and other function calls will still look at the original array. Instead you must *mutate* the object that all those `queue` variables refer to and then they will all see the change.

Answer (score 0):

to stop iteration on offspring and siblings after reaching the cell that has been searched you should use the return value in three places:

first,when reaching the desired cell you should notify the recursive instances about to happen that the search has ended:

```
        } else {
            alert('The end!');
            return false;
        }
```

the second return command should be in the forEach loop in order to stop iterating the node's children if we have found the requested cell:

```
                      if (!drawBreadthFirstSearch(current, start, last, queue, animation_speed)) return false;
```

the third return command should be on the last function's line and it stands for: still haven't found the cell, continue searching:

```
        }, animation_speed);
        return true;
   }
```